# Could AI be used to detect when a human is picking survey response options randomly?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, randomness

Context: I am a clinical psych researcher dabbling in machine learning.

Humans cannot be truly random. Therefore, could machine learning be used to analyze a string of numbers and determine the probability that said string was generated by a human or by a computer? Taking it a step further, could machine learning be used to look at survey responses and determine the likelihood as to whether the participant was answering questions honestly, or whether they "Christmas-tree'd" either part of or all of the survey? If so, would this be dependent on the specific questions that each survey item asked, or simply on the type of survey question (e.g., Likert-type, sliding scale, ruler, yes/no or true/false questions, free response, etc.)?

Comment: You could just ask a small number of questions two different ways, and see if the answers agree.

Comment: You are asking different questions. 1) "whether they Christmas-tree'd either part of or all of the survey" - should be pretty easy to detect given enough learning, even if you don't have control over the questions. 2) "probability that said string was generated by a human or by a computer" - this may be tricky. E.g. assume that you have a neural network which determines whether the answers are human-generated. Then one may use this NN as a base to create a generator for human-like inputs.

Comment: @Dmitry you are correct; poor choice of wording on my part. The first question is much more in line with what I'm trying to say; I imagine a NN that can look at raw data, highlight suspect responses, and report which responses may be Christmas-tree'd and how confident the NN is in its response, if that makes sense. Apologies; my education in this area is entirely self-directed, so I apologize if my phrasing isn't entirely correct.

Comment: This seems more appropriate in [stats.se] or [datascience.se].

Answer (score 2):

AI is probably not the best tool for this job.  Several classical techniques in survey design include:

- Consistency check: ask the same question in several ways, spread out across the survey, and check if they've answered consistently.
- Open-ended questions: ask an open-ended question, see if they write nonsense or the bare minimum.
- Attention check questions: e.g., "What is your favorite color?  Regardless of your favorite color, please pick the second option."  Beware that these are controversial and have pros and cons.
- Recruitment: recruit subjects who are less likely to try to cheat you.  Pay them a reasonable wage for their time.

My experience is that it is easy to be overly worried about respondents answering dishonestly; if you follow basic good practices, the overwhelming majority of respondents will try to be helpful and won't try to cheat you.

Comment: Yes, these are all good suggestions and I utilize these, despite their individual unique flaws (though the last suggestion has some ethical implications; I work with folks of low socioeconomic status and folks in third-world countries, where what we might call a "fair wage" would be seen as coercion). I'm just asking y'all to humor me; if one were to do this, could it be done with ML and (roughly) how would it be done? I'm more interested in this from a theoretical standpoint (though an extra arrow in my quiver to detect false responses is never unwelcome, should I have the time to make that).

Comment: @Snou, sounds hard to validate.  It's not clear where you'd get the training data or what patterns would be indicative of dishonesty, or how you'd verify it.  I imagine there'd be a lingering doubt about whether you are wrongly ignoring valid answers.  I suppose whether it is possible in theory depends on whether there is a particular pattern that dishonest people follow (there might be, or there might not; that seems like an empirical question, rather than one of theory), but I am skeptical that it'd be terribly useful in practice, because of these challenges.